Unable to set AWS ALB listener routing actions using the AWS ingress controller
Unable to set the AWS ingress controller annotation to specify a listener target group. When I deploy the ingress, it always sets the routing actions as 'Return fixed response.' I need to set it to 'Forward to target groups' and specify the target group ARN.
Here are my current annotations:
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: xxx-eck-alb
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "xxx-eck-alb-tg"
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /t1demo/plugin/de.elo.ix.plugin.proxy/web/
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-xxx


To forward traffic to a specific target group with the AWS ALB Ingress Controller, add this annotation:
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.my-action: >
{"Type": "forward", "TargetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:targetgroup/my-target-group/abcdef123456"}
Details:
Custom Action: alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions. defines a custom action.
Forward Traffic: The JSON specifies the action type as forward and includes the TargetGroupArn.
Replace my-action with your action name and the ARN with your target group's ARN.
